# What's the right way to navigate in main screen from child widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter, so my question is:
my app have a MainScreen.dart that have a widget from another file named [PostsScreen.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Dge.png), like that:

**MainScreen.dart**

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
      ),
      home: Scaffold(,
          body: PostScreen()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**PostsScreen.dart**

```
...
return GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
 Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => DetailScreen(data: posts[index]),
  ),
 );
},
...
```

After tap on one of the PostScreen element expected navigate to [DetailScreen.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHXPy.png) outside of MainScreen, but it maked inside with two AppBars.

Am I right that I should pass the route name from DetailScreen to its parent PostsScreen and pass it to MainScreen for change screen outside of last? Or what's right way for do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need to build another ```PostScreen``` when you can return the contents directly in ```MainScreen``` itself ?

Comment: Main screen will contain many widgets like:
1. PostsScreen
2. NewsScreen
3. CasesScreen etc.

Too much code in one file, so ....

Comment: Okay , then don't return ```Scaffold``` to the other screens. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, thx, will try. But in this case i miss the changes in AppBar (like back arrow etc.)